# Stuff drawn by paintComponent() disappear after calling repaint()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

On Head First Java book we're seeing some little animation and I'm trying to draw an animation that traces out a diagonal line. I'm doing so by using the paintComponent() method and drawing an oval at x,y (values which are updated each time through the loop). Why do I lose the previously drawn ovals? According to the book I should be getting a smear on the screen where the previously drawn ovals are not lost. This should need fixing by adding to the paintComponent() method a white background every time repaint() is called but instead i'm not getting the 'mistake'. **Why is this and how do I get to KEEP the previously drawn ovals on the panel?** 
 Using JDK 13.0.2 and Mac OSX Catalina

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleAnimation {

    int x = 70;
    int y = 70;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
            x++;
            y++;
            drawPanel.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (Exception ex){};

        }
    }
    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
        }
    } // close inner class
} // close outer class
```

Comment: Assuming you're running from the EDT (you should if you're not already), you definitely don't want to use `Thread.sleep()` in a swing app. Instead, use a swing `Timer` for animations.

Comment: Haven't learned about Threads yet. Is that what prevents the smear of ovals?

Comment: @vader, no, thread is a separate sequence of commands execution. Think several processor cores, each with own list of commands it must run (but in Java it's emulated and scheduled, and... you get the idea). Most Java apps have multiple of those, and Swing in particular has a thing called "UI thread" which is responsible for drawing the app, and you ideally never should want to make it sleep, because then UI becomes unresponsive.

Comment: The code you posted is NOT complete. We don't know how the go() method is invoked, so we don't know if your code is executed on the EDT or not. If the code is executing on the EDT then you cause the EDT to sleep which means the frame can't repaint itself. If it is not on the EDT then you should see the "smearing" of circles. But without executable code we can't tell for sure what you are doing.

Comment: go() is called on main()

Comment: Don't tell us. Post the exact code you are executing. So we can copy/paste/compile/text. The is called an [mre]. A "MRE" should be posted with every question.

Comment: Thanks, just did. Will do for future questions @camickr

Comment: Do you actually get a correct animation when you run it? The oval moves around the screen for a centain amount of time? Or is there just 1 oval in the end position?

Comment: I'll report this other person's struggles here as well: https://coderanch.com/t/629000/java/repaint-automatically-erasing-circle - it shows that this is not the only instance of confusion caused by platform being "too smar".

Answer (score 1):

> Is that what prevents the smear of ovals?

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
    }
```

The code should be:

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // added
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
    }
```

You need the `super.paintComponent(g)` to clear the background of the panel before doing the custom painting.

> Yeah, great book. The output i'm getting with the code as is, is the "corrected version"

Edit:

The book is correct. You need to understand how the EDT works. When you start an application the code invoked in the main() method executes on a separate Thread. Swing events and painting is done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). So invoking sleep() in the go() method should NOT affect the painting of the circle and you should see the smear. If you only see a single oval painted after the loop is finished, then this imples your IDE or platform starts the code in the main() method on the EDT, which is not normal.

You can verify my above statement by adding:

```
System.out.println( SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() );
```

to your loop to see if it is executing on the EDT or not.

Comment: Without adding the super call, the drawn ovals are removed automatically. I want to know how to keep them, since the book says that my code should keep all previously drawn ovals and look as a diagonal thick line was drawn across the screen. Why is it not right now?

Comment: What you are describing is the opposite of what should happen. Post your [mre].

Comment: When I run your code I see the "smear" of the ovals on the screen because as expected the background is NOT cleared. If you add the statement I suggest above then the background IS cleared and you only ever see a single oval. I am using JDK8 on Windows 7. If you are having problems, maybe it is your platform.

Comment: I tried adding the isEventDispatchThread() and it printed "false". I'm using Java 13.0.2 and OSX Catalina

Comment: Then you should be seeing the "smear" of the circles as the rest of us are seeing (which is correct). You still haven't clarified your platform. Maybe somebody else using your platform needs to run the code. Add your version/platform to the question and hope someone else answers the question.

Comment: Where can I find the version of java I'm using?

Comment: from the command line I just use: "java -version". If you use an IDE I don't know how to tell. You should know by the version you installed on your system.

Comment: Version 13.0.2 and using MacOSx Catalina

Comment: Right, so it is the Mac that is clearing the background of the panel, not Swing.

Comment: You solve it by doing painting properly. A Swing component should be responsible for completely painting its state (it should not rely on the platform to achieve the desired painting effect). Therefore it should always clear the background and then do its required painting. If you want to see multiple circle objects on the panel, then you need to paint multiple circle objects on the panel. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways this can be achieved.

Comment: @camickr, the link from a while back: https://coderanch.com/t/629000/java/repaint-automatically-erasing-circle - suggests this is more than "you should paint properly" kind of problem. There whether the sample works depends on buffering that the platform internally does, which might depend on settings external to Swing.